# Bosun: send authentication token in the notification section

Tags: bosun

I want Bosun to make an API call to JIRA, which requires a basic authentication in a form of BASE64 encoded string username:password. What keyword I can use in the notification definition to pass the authentication token to JIRA? My basic notification looks like this:

```
notification jira_alert {
    post = https://example.com:8081/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta
    contentType = application/json
```

Reading the documentation on bosun.org I can't find any specific keyword I could use. Any hints?

Answer (score -1):

Can you put put the key in URL or in JSON data?
For example:

```
notifaction chat {
    next = email  
    timeout = 10m
    post - http://chat.example.com/room/1?key=KEY&message=whatever
}
```